# Convert string type dict into python dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Suppose i have string variable named 'ds'.

```
ds="{'a': 1, 'b':2}"
```

And i want to store it in another variable named 'do'.

```
do=some_function(ds)
```

So that, when i do this,

```
print(do['a'])
```

My output should be `1`.

So how do i do that using some in build functions or some small code?

Comment: https://www.calazan.com/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-dictionary-in-python/ just a google...

Comment: thats not what ur asking but you accept the answer that implements the exact thing its demonstrating... lol

Comment: @L_Church My bad, sorry man.

Comment: is cool have a good day :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import ast
ds="{'a': 1, 'b':2}"
do=ast.literal_eval(ds)
print(do['a'])
```

**ast — Abstract Syntax Trees**

The ast module helps Python applications to process trees of the Python abstract syntax grammar. The abstract syntax itself might change with each Python release; this module helps to find out programmatically what the current grammar looks like.

```
ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)
```

Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.

Link For doc

> https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer so that it can be helpful for others also?

Comment: @ Uwe Plonus added details about ast and ast.literal_eval(node_or_string) for more details go to link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval go through this @LeviLesches

Comment: Oh okay thanks. (I see how wiping the hard drive could POTENTIALLY be a bad thing)